# ¿El nombre de unas fuerzas de seguridad ficticias iría en mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: traducción, ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

En el juego VA-11 HALL-A, las fuerzas de seguridad de la ciudad de llaman "White Knights" (con mayúsculas) en inglés.

[Según la RAE](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/policia-ejercito-inicial-mayuscula-o-minuscula-1050/), las fuerzas de seguridad, policía, ejército van en minúscula (asumo que también incluye palabras como gendarmería/gendarme, federal/federale, etc.).

La pregunta sería, en español ¿"White Knights" contaría como nombre propio (Caballeros Blancos) , o su puesto como fuerzas públicas de seguridad significaría que iría en minúscula (caballeros blancos)?

Si va en mayúscula, ¿cómo se llamaría a una persona que forma parte de esa organización? ¿"Un Caballero Blanco", o "Un caballero blanco"?

¿En femenino sería "Un caballero blanco" o "Una caballera blanca"? Sé que "caballera" se le llama a un caballero mujer, pero no estoy seguro si el hecho de que la organización en sí se llame "Caballeros blancos" quiera decir que la persona que forme parte no puede usar el sustantivo "caballero" en femenino.

Answer (score 2):

El enlace que adjuntas parece bastante claro al respecto. Cuando se hable de la institución se hará con mayúsculas y cuando se hable de sus miembros irá en minúsculas.

En tu primera frase estarías hablando de la institución:

> En el juego VA-11 HALL-A, las fuerzas de seguridad de la ciudad de llaman "White Knights"

Podemos modificar ligeramente una de las frases de ejemplo que aparecen en el enlace para hablar de un grupo de elementos pertenecientes a ese cuerpo:

> Los caballeros blancos cargan contra los manifestantes laicos y los expulsan de Sol

Si nos referimos a un único miembro del cuerpo, también iría en minúsculas

> El caballero blanco detuvo al ladrón

No estoy de acuerdo contigo en el empleo de "caballera" para referirte a un miembro femenino de esa organización. Si te fijas en [la entrada del DLE](https://dle.rae.es/caballero), las acepciones relacionadas con tu pregunta están marcadas con una "m" de masculino

> 6. m. Miembro de una orden civil o militar. Caballero de Alcántara.
> 7. m. Miembro de una orden de caballería.
> 8. m. U. como tratamiento de los alumnos de academias militares y de miembros de algún cuerpo castrense. Caballero guardiamarina. Caballero
>    legionario.

Independientemente del sexo de la persona referida, el nombre siempre es masculino.
Si quieres identificar el sexo debes fijarte en el determinante o los adjetivos que acompañan al nombre.

> Una **agente** de policía alta y morena.

Justamente en la Legión Española se encontraron con el mismo problema que tú cuando las mujeres se incorporaron al ejército y lo solucionaron llamándolas **damas legionarias**.

Comment: Entonces sería por ejemplo, "¿Qué piensas de los Caballeros Blancos?" porque están hablando de la organización, pero "Nunca he conocido un caballero blanco" porque están hablando de un hipotético miembro.

Comment: @Doc Creo que sí

Answer (score 0):

Veo muy absurdo lo de: caballero blanco

Os pongo el caso en novelas:

Si lo pones en minúscula, ¿cómo sabes que no se refiere a un "señor" de piel blanca, por ejemplo? No vas a repetir constantemente: El caballero de piel blanca blandió la espada y le atravesó.

Supongamos una orden de caballeros: Los Caballeros Blancos. Lo escribirás siempre en mayúscula:

- El Caballero Blanco blandió la espada y le atravesó.

Comment: Una vez más, la contextualización es la clave. Si la RAE ha determinado esto es porque no encuentra manera de justificar el uso de mayúsculas cuando en la mayoría de casos se pueden utilizar alternativas o por puro contexto no hay opción a duda.